how to read Matlab duration object from Python?
I create a Matlab duration object and save it to a .mat file:
timeend = seconds(123);
save('time.mat', timeend, '-v7.3');

Then I read it from Python:
with h5py.File('time.mat', 'r') as f:

    var = f['timeend'][:]
    print(list(var))

Then var is a np object:
[array([3707764736,          2,          1,          1,          1,
                1], dtype=uint32)]

How to convert this Numpy array to a timedelta object or an np.array of the time in seconds?

Instead of dealing with h5py and a mat file, you can easily deal with numpy and a txt file.
Matlab
For example, I created a duration array in Matlab (H,M,S) and I converted it to seconds by using the seconds function provided.
% duration array: 12h, 50m, 24s
hours = 12;
min = 50;
sec = 24;
time = duration(hours, min, sec);

% conversion to seconds
time_sec = seconds(time);

% save variable to ASCII file
save time_sec.txt time_sec -ascii

Python
In Python you just need to load the txt file, read it with numpy and create the timedelta object.
from datetime import timedelta
import numpy as np

time_sec = np.take(np.loadtxt("time_sec.txt"),0)

# time_delta object
time_delta = timedelta(seconds=time_sec)
print(time_delta)


As a result:
12:50:24

Extra
Even with the days function in Matlab it works:
MATLAB:
time = days(5);
time_sec = seconds(time);
...

PYTHON RESULT:
5 days, 0:00:00

Take it easy, when you can.
PS: in this simple way a matrix of duration or seconds can be written in the txt file and a timedelta object matrix can be created in python with a slight modification of the code.
